# Mounted engine on a ruby on rails application sends NoMethodError message when trying to edit a record from the host application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a mounted engine on an application with Rails 5.2.8.1

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/countries", as: 'country_table'
  
end
```

Here are the routes for the engine

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope module: 'table' do
    post '/', action: 'index'
    get '/:id/edit', action: 'edit'
    post '/:id/update', action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

In the host application I have a Country model which I am trying to edit. I have a few seeds in my DB.

```
7.times do |i|
    country = Country.new
    country.name = "Country#{i}"
    country.save
end
```

Here is my controler

```
module MyEngine
  class TableController < ApplicationController

    def edit
      # Identify the resource
      @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    
      # render the form
      render :edit
    end
```

This is my edit.html.erb view

```
<%= form_with model: @country do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end  %>
```

When I hit `http://localhost:3000/countries/3/edit` I get this error

```
NoMethodError in MyEngine::Table#edit

undefined method `country_path' for #<#<Class:0x000055aa7e4cbc50>:0x000055aa7e5478a0>
Did you mean?  country_table
```

If someone knows what is wrong here, I will listen carefully...

Comment: when you type `rails routes` from the command line (terminal) what are the routes listed that pertain to 'country'?

Comment: `rails routes` gives me `country_table      /countries                                                                               WcmcComponents::Engine` but I have realised that I haven't got a controller for my Country model in the host application and I am wondering if that isn't the problem

Comment: the engine should be self-contained. The countries_controller should be in the engine. But you have called it TableController, I'm not sure why. It should be called CountriesController (in a file called countries_controller.rb)